# Stuck at Syncing files to device Chrome when trying to run a web project

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-channel

I'm stuck at Syncing files to device Chrome when running the project, the same result from vscode terminal and command prompt, I only get a white screen on a google window and it doesn't seem to be in progress anymore, the steps that I made to create the project are :

```
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade 
flutter config --enable-web
flutter create webapp
cd webapp
flutter run
```

I tried to check the console with F12 on the browser but it is empty.
I can run the project only in the release mode with `flutter run --release`, but it so exhausting to test on this mode seen that the hot reload takes so much time.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use `beta` channel for [web support](https://flutter.dev/web) in flutter.

```dart
flutter channel beta
```

Comment: I have switched the channel and created a new project, still the same issue

Comment: Try this `flutter clean` than `flutter run -d chrome` in VS code terminal.

Comment: Try to use `flutter run -v -d chrome` to make verbose output. Maybe it gives some more information.

Comment: here you go mate 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8U2v.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkBV4.png

Comment: I am confused with `flutter stuff` directory. Please remove space char or replace it with undescore. This is Windows... space matters.

Comment: this is just a folder in windows it contains another folder that is called Projects, i runned the  command flutter create webbapp3 under this folder, could it make problems ?

Comment: I understand but suddenly it affects on Chrome debug session running. Usually for run commands in Windows which contains spaces we must wrap the command in double quotes.

Comment: Did you update packages after switch channel `fluter packages get`?

Comment: No I didn't do that, is it necessary ?

Comment: if it is, should I switch to beta channel then upgrade then do flutter packages get then create a new project ?